# Basic application of Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The probability of undergraduate-student who smokes is 13%.

The probability of postgraduate-student who smokes is 27%.

In a school, there are 1/5 undergraduate-student and 4/5 postgraduate-student.

The question is: Using Bayes theorem, calculate the probability for a student (in school) who smokes is a postgraduate-student.

I encountered this problem in my exam and couldn't figure out the solution, hope someone can help.

Comment: This is a very basic application of Bayes' theorem. Without details on how you got confused, it will be hard to help. For example, can you state Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: First I applied Bayes theorem like @jvdhooft but then I couldn't calculate P[A,B] and P[B], I think I have a misunderstanding between P[A|B] and P[A,B]

Comment: As @Stella Biderman said you, it is not a "weird problem" but a basic application of Bayes' theorem. This is why I have changed your title. In a more general way, don't use "weird" especially in titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bayes' theorem states that $P[A | B] = \frac{P[A, B]}{P[B]}$. Let us call S being a smoker and G being a postgraduate student:

$$P[G | S] = \frac{P[G, S]}{P[S]} = \frac{0.8 \cdot 0.27}{0.2 \cdot 0.13 + 0.8 \cdot 0.27} \approx 0.893$$

Comment: Thank you I feel so dumb now